# Invalid WEB_CMD configuration option: Relative pathname: "/bin/false"

Tags: ubuntu, rkhunter, chkrootkit

I am on Ubuntu, I am trying to install rkhunter.

I've tried

`apt-get install rkhunter`

success

But then, I did

`rkhunter --update`

I kept getting

> Invalid WEB_CMD configuration option: Relative pathname: "/bin/false"

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem but [found the following fix](https://churchill.ddns.me.uk/post/rkhunter-invalid-web-cmd-configuration-option/):

Open `/etc/rkhunter.conf`. Uncomment (remove the # to the left) and change the following three variables:

```
MIRRORS_MODE=1 ---> MIRRORS_MODE=0

UPDATE_MIRRORS=0 ---> UPDATE_MIRRORS=1

WEB_CMD="/bin/false" ---> WEB_CMD=""
```

`--versioncheck` and `--update` should now work.

I believe the well-written comments in `/etc/rkhunter.conf` explain each variable clearly, but, in the *tl;dr* spirit, here's my quick interpretation of what is happening:

The default `MIRRORS_MODE=1` tells rkhunter to only use local mirrors, but you have to define them in the mirrors file for this setting to work. Switching to `MIRRORS_MODE=0` allows rkhunter to use any mirror.

The default `UPDATE_MIRRORS=0` only allows the mirrors file to be updated manually. Switching to `UPDATE_MIRRORS=1` allows rkhunter to update the file during the `--update` operation.

The default `WEB_CMD="/bin/false"` [purposely blocks](https://tracker.debian.org/news/856557) rkhunter from connecting to mirrors for [security reasons](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2017-7480). Switching to `WEB_CMD=""` re-enables rkhunter's ability to do mirror updates.

However, considering this function was purposely disabled for security reasons, it's seems like it may be best to update rkhunter using the package manager. That's what I plan to do. Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently it is caused by a security update that disabled remote downloading of updates. I have seen the recommendation to replace in `/etc/rkhunter.conf`:

```
WEB_CMD="/bin/false"
```

with

```
WEB_CMD=""
```

However, I don't see the point since the update will fail. I think you should leave it to `/bin/false`, ignore the message and rely on aptitude for the updates.

Answer (score 0):

If cURL is installed on your system, which is likely, I prefer setting WEB_CMD=curl as the documentation specifically says there is no default value.

Comment: This does not add to the approved answer given by @fixxOrz two years ago.

Comment: I tried this and it failed on my Debian OS even though I have curl installed. For example: `Checking file mirrors.dat [ Update failed ]` ...